# \vspace not working inside tikzpicture environemnt

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a figure using tikz, and by now, the code looks like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, very thick](0,0) circle (3cm);

\draw[black, thick](3,0)--(3.5,0);
\hspace{3.5cm}\text{$+\Omega$}\hspace{-3.5cm}

\draw[black, thick](-3.51,0)--(-4.01,0);
\hspace{-4.56cm}\text{$-\Omega$}\hspace{4.56cm}

\draw[black, thick](-1,-3)--(-1,-3.5);
\hspace{-1.1cm}\vspace{3.5cm}
\text{$0$}
\hspace{1.1cm}\vspace{-3.5cm}

\draw[black, thick](-1,3)--(-1,3.5);
\hspace{-1.1cm}\vspace{-3.5cm}
\text{$\infty$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

This creates the following figure:

[image]

As you can see, \vspace didn't do anything, both 0 and ∞ are still in the center, can I make they go down and up using \vspace? If not, what can I do to put the characters in their designed position?

Comment: Any text outside a node is ignored, including \vspace and \hspace.

Comment: @JohnKormylo really? But \hspace still works, I was able to put +omega and -omega on their respective sides

Comment: Oops, text itself is ignored, but marcros are expanded, although they may not make sense in the context.  You might also look at \pgftext (page 1078).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop, iterating over the labels defined by the iteration variable `\lab`.

#### What does the variable `\lab` do?

This variable `\lab` takes successively the values of the list `{\infty, -\Omega, 0, +\Omega}`. Then it counts them with `count=\n` and by calculating the angles with  `evaluate=\n as \angle using \n*90`:

1. First, the variable `\lab` will take the value `\infty`, the counter `\n` is initialized to `1` and the angle `\angle` is `1*90=90°`.
2. Then `\lab` will take the second value `-\Omega`, the `\n` counter is incremented by `1` and is therefore worth `2`; the angle is then `2*90=180°`,
3. etc.

Thus the loop code:

```
\foreach \lab[count=\n,evaluate=\n as \angle using \n*90] 
    in {\infty,-\Omega,0,+\Omega}
        {\draw (\angle:3cm)--(\angle:3.5cm) node[]{$\lab$};}
```

is equivalent to the following code:

```
\draw (90:3cm)--(90:3.5cm) node[]{$\infty$};
\draw (180:3cm)--(180:3.5cm) node[]{$-\Omega$};
\draw (270:3cm)--(270:3.5cm) node[]{$0$};
\draw (360:3cm)--(360:3.5cm) node[]{$+\Omega$};
```

`shift={(\angle:3mm)}`allows you to move the label so that it does not overlap the line. For this move, I use polar coordinates which allow me to offset these latter.

I improved the code using the `anchors`, which allows placing the labels as close as possible to the lines. So the spacing between text and lines is identical everywhere.

#### 1. Without shift: labels overlap the line

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, very thick](0,0) circle (3cm);
\foreach \lab[count=\n,evaluate=\n as \angle using \n*90] 
    in {\infty,-\Omega,0,+\Omega}
        {\draw (\angle:3cm)--(\angle:3.5cm) node[]{$\lab$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### 2. With shift: no overlap but bad spacing

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, very thick](0,0) circle (3cm);
\foreach \lab[count=\n,evaluate=\n as \angle using \n*90] 
    in {\infty,-\Omega,0,+\Omega}
        {\draw (\angle:3cm)--(\angle:3.5cm)
            node[shift={(\angle:3mm)}]{$\lab$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### 3. With the anchors : better spacing

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, very thick](0,0) circle (3cm);
\foreach \lab[count=\n,evaluate=\n as \angle using \n*90] 
    in {\infty,-\Omega,0,+\Omega}
        {\draw (\angle:3cm)--(\angle:3.5cm)node [anchor=\angle-180]{$\lab$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting way! I think I understand, but could you say what \lab and shift do? Thanks in advance

Comment: I just added explanations, is it clearer now?

Comment: I still don't understand what \lab does, but the way you explained is amazing! I already know how to use it, and that is already fine for me, thank you!

Comment: I've added explanations, am I clearer now?

Comment: much clearer man, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I do wonder where you got that method from.

To add text in TikZ diagrams, you use `node`s. They can be appended to the end of paths, e.g. `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node{foo};`, or added separately, e.g. `\node at (1,1) {foo};`. A node can also take options defining its shape, color etc., and the position. For example `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node[above] {foo};` places the node above `(1,1)`.

So one way of doing your diagram:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, very thick](0,0) circle (3cm);

\draw[black, thick](3,0)--(3.5,0) node[right] {$+\Omega$};

\draw[black, thick](-3,0)--(-3.5,0) node[left] {$-\Omega$};

\draw[black, thick](0,-3)--(0,-3.5) node[below] {$0$};

\draw[black, thick](0,3)--(0,3.5) node[above] {$\infty$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hahaha I had no idea nodes existed, I'm AFK right now, but I'll try it tomorrow, just wanted to thank you sir